# Hide DIVs by ID on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following JS in the page layout (running RoR):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('5').style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to have the 5 `div`s to be hidden on page load but can not seem to get it to work. I can use JS or JQuery. I have tried this as well:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  ...js code...
});
```

and still could not get it to hide the `div`s on page load.

What do I need to write in JS to have `div` with `id` 1..5 to be hidden?

Comment: If you want them to be hidden on page load why not just put a css class on each one that has a `display:none` property, ie `class="hidden"`? Other than that what does your html look like, are you getting errors on the console?

Comment: do those elements exist at he time the code is run?

Comment: These questions are suggesting a number of possible solutions but I think to get you a solid answer we need to see your HTML at the time the page loads as well as your proposed JavaScript.  Otherwise, we don't really know whether document.getElementById is simply not finding the DOM eleemnts, or if something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First, it isn't recommended that `id`s start with numbers. Just compatibility issues, don't ask me.

Second, your code is particularly redundant and it nullifies the purpose of having `id`s. Use a common class or less redundant yet just nest them all in a container and grab all the children.

```
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container div").hide();
});
```

Calling `.show` and `.hide` toggles the `display: none` CSS attribute.

Comment: Actually an element's [id can start with digits or even be all digits](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#the-id-attribute). The only restriction is no space characters. It is only suggested to start with a letter for compatibility reasons. [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gdk17ee9/)

Answer (score -2):

If you use jQuery just do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("id").hide()
});
```

Comment: This is not valid jQuery